# How to get all local variables in Node.js when an uncaught exception happens?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, dump

Whenever my node.js script has an uncaught exception. I'd like to be able to dump all the local variables to the console implicitly so that I can have a snapshot of all the values the moment anything went wrong.

Right now I can do this with visual code by having a debugger running, but is this possible to do using just code?

If not, what would be the best way to invoke a debugger to attach to the node script and dump the variables when an exception occurs?

Currently the built in node.js debugger has the `watch()` method for getting the variable values on an exception, but it requires that you implicitly specify the variable before the exception occurs.

There is the chrome v8 debugger using `--inspect` argument and visiting `chrome://inspect/` in chrome, but that would require automating chrome using the Chrome DevTools Protocol.

It also requires an instance of chrome to be running which is too resource intensive on a VPS that has the minimum specs.

What is the best way to dump the local variables to a log file when something goes wrong?